# image taking more space than its size

Tags: android, image, user-interface, constraints

I'm building an app with an image in the menu that changes according to the user choice. I set it to `match_constraint` in the height, and `wrap_content` in the width of the image. However, after the image changes it uses a lot more space than it should, and my second image(where the size is set to `match_constraint`) is getting to small.

Here are some visible examples:

[image]

[image]

The constraints:
[image]

The image resource:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful if you post the entire layout xml rather than just images, but I can see some potential solutions to your problem:

- Add `android:scaleType="centerInside"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your image. This makes it so the image scales to the size you defined while keeping the aspect ratio and not "overflowing" outside of its boundaries.
- It is possible your constraints aren't well defined, but in order to know that the full xml is required.

I'd recommend trying the first approach though, as it usually fixes my problems regarding image sizing

Comment: The first answer worked great, thank you very much !
You saved me a lot of time !